# Nginx error upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Im running mu Nginx as revers proxy to serv content from remote url , it was working fine for while ,  when i moved it to another host , i start getting the following erros
i tested internet though new host all is fine evern nginx serv from root location without issue but when i request a location that serv as revers proxt am getting

> 8583#0: *2 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while
>   connecting to upstream, client: 10.64.159.12, server: xxxxx.com,
>   request: "GET /web/rest/v1/story/656903.json HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "http://requestedurl.com:80/web/rest/v1/story/656903.json", host: "myurl.com"

Location Config :

```
location /data {
            sub_filter 'http' 'https';
            sub_filter_once off;
            sub_filter_types application/json;
            proxy_read_timeout 300;
            proxy_pass  http://url here ;
            proxy_redirect       off;
            proxy_set_header     Host $host;
            proxy_set_header  Accept-Encoding  "";
```

Any advise